# Oracle: using an attribute in the projection that is not in the group by

Tags: sql, oracle

(Edited below in response to answer)

Assume that I have a table R(a,b) with no primary key nor any other constraints.

```
dmg@[local] test1=# table R;
 a | b  
---+----
 1 | 10
 1 | 20
 2 | 30
 2 | 10
(4 rows)
```

the query

```
select a,b 
from R group a ;
```

is invalid in Postgresql (it would be ok if a is the primary key of R).

```
dmg@[local] test1=# select a,b from R group by a;
ERROR:  column "r.b" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select a,b from R group by a;
             ^
```

But it is allowed in sqlite3. It chooses a value of b from a tuple within each subset (non deterministically).

```
sqlite> select a,b from R group by a;
a           b         
----------  ----------
1           10        
2           30
```

Does oracle execute this query as valid?

Comment: It would make much more sense to explain **what** problem you are trying to solve (the business problem that lead you to where you are now), rather than how you think it may be solved in a different database product.

Comment: I don't have a business problem. I am curious about the query itself. I teach databases but I don't have access to an Oracle instance.

Comment: Even so. You would state a (made-up) "real life" problem first, right? What is the assignment here - to select one (quasi) random row from each group, where "group" is defined as "same value in the `a` column"? There are ways to do that in Oracle (and in any other product), just not the one that works - or may work - in some product in direct violation of SQL standard requirements.

Comment: My goal is to understand semantics before I apply them to a real world problem. IMO, one that understands the theory is better prepared to solve the real life problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is no longer accepted in MySQL,.

Second, it does not return a "random" value.  It returns a value from an indeterminate row.

Third, it violates the SQL standard.

And finally, Oracle does not support this syntax.

Comment: And you can access Oracle at livesql.oracle.com

Comment: @BobC . . . Or more simply at a site like db<>fiddle.